# How to use attribut selector for corresponding class?

Tags: css, css-selectors

```
<div class="myclass class1"></div>
```

Simple class selector is to be like this:

```
.myclass.class1{/*....*/}
```

But how to select it with attribute selector?

I've tried like this:

```
.myclass[class^=class]{/*....*/}
```

But not working!

---

If it was `<div class="myclass"><div class="class1"></div></div>`:

Then this would work: `.myclass [class^=class]{/*....*/}`

---

Amazingly this would work: `.myclass[class*=class]{/*.....*/}` but why not with `^`?

---

Yeah I know I can just use `[class^=class]{/*....*/}` but I need to apply styles only for `.myclass.class....`

---

[working demo with *](http://jsfiddle.net/KVhU8/4/)

[not working demo with ^](http://jsfiddle.net/KVhU8/5/)

Comment: Why is there even a [css-bug] tag ಠ_ಠ

Comment: * is working ^ is not working thus added css-bug

Comment: Uh.. please don't go assuming something is a bug just because it doesn't work the way you expect it to.

Comment: So, could you please explain why it is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
.myclass[class^="myclass class"]{
    color: blue;
}
```

[attr^=value]
Represents an element with an attribute name of attr and whose value is prefixed by "value"

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/KVhU8/2/)**</kbd>

Comment: C-link: check demo once.

Comment: it's amazing but why not ^ working?

Comment: Even ^ is working. Check demo once.

Comment: you did it taking div so it's working.

Comment: then what if I have myclasstest then it would also take to that.

Comment: Look at this http://jsfiddle.net/KVhU8/3/ which is not working!

Comment: Hey look at this updated one. http://jsfiddle.net/KVhU8/2/

Comment: you are selecting myclass too! But I need myclass.class... only

Comment: Yes. You should select my class too. Otherwise css attribute selector will understand that you have class name ends with|starts with| contains only one string (i.e., class1/class2... etc)

Comment: if there is no class1 in correspondence with myclass then it would also take css for myclass what I don't need.

Comment: No It wont take css. Look at the demo url that I shared in answer. Last div has class "myclass test" and css is not rendered to this div.

Comment: Oh! Thanks. This is the way working.